# How to make value in autocomplete jquery ui?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

In my `user` table I have `id_user` and `name`. My autocomplete searches only by name. I need `id_user` to input into the database. Usually, we can write `id_user` as a value attribute in the input tag. This is the code :

Controller :

```
function get_autocomplete(){
        if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
            $result = $this->User_model->search($_GET['term']);
            if (count($result) > 0) {
            foreach ($result as $row)
                $arr_result[] = $row->name;
                echo json_encode($arr_result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Model :

```
function search($name){
        $this->db->like('name', $name , 'both');
        $this->db->order_by('name', 'ASC');
        $this->db->limit(10);
        return $this->db->get('user')->result();
    }
```

View :

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="id_user">
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
              source: "<?php echo site_url('admin/user/get_autocomplete/?');?>"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill the autocomplete options with Label/Value pairs.
So the options show the label (e.g. `username`) and when the user selects one option the value (e.g. `id_user`) is written to the input field (= the value and is therefor it's displayed in the input field)

So your php code should return a `JSON` array with label/value pairs

```
foreach ($result as $row)
    $arr_result[] = array('label' => $row->name, 'value' => $row->id_user);
}
echo json_encode($arr_result);
```

Please take a look at my jsfiddle example - it shows the autocomplete with static data
https://jsfiddle.net/jf7ynxwz/3/

If you don't like the user_id to be written into the input (visible) it's a little bit more complicated. Have a look into the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change) and maybe set the value as an data-html attribute of the input after selection :-)